# getting TypeError: movieDetails.map is not a function when try to use useState in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import request from "../../requests";
import { fetchMovies } from "../../feautures/movies/moviesSlice";
import "./SingleMoviePage.scss";
import Rating from "../../components/UI/Rating/Rating";
import axios from "axios";

const SingleMoviePage = ({ match }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [movieDetails, setMovieDetails] = useState({})

  /*  params */
  const movieId = match.params.id;
  const page = match.params.page;
  const genre = match.params.genre;

  /* movies reducer handle */
  const movies = useSelector((state) => state.movies.movies);
  const moviesStatus = useSelector((state) => state.movies.status);

  /* movieDetails reducer handle */


  /* base urls */
  const baseImgUrl = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original";
  const movieDetailUrl = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${movieId}?api_key=c057c067b76238e7a64d3ba8de37076e&language=en-US`;


  
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async() => {
      let response = await axios.get(movieDetailUrl);
      response = response.data;
      setMovieDetails(response)
    }

    fetchData()

  },[movieDetailUrl])
  console.log("data: ",movieDetails )

  


  let content;
  if (moviesStatus === "loading") {
    <div>Loading ...</div>;
  } else if (moviesStatus === "succeeced") {
    let movie = movies.find((movie) => movie.id.toString() === movieId);
    content = (
      <div
        className="single-movie__container"
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url(${
            movie.backdrop_path
              ? baseImgUrl + movie.backdrop_path
              : baseImgUrl + movie.poster_path
          })`,
        }}
      >
        <div className="single-movie__information">
          <h1 className="single-movie__title">{movie.title}</h1>
          <div className="single-movie__rate">
            <Rating
              rating={movie.vote_average}
              className="single-movie__stars"
            />
            <div className="single-movie__average">
              {movie.vote_average}(Imdb)
            </div>
          </div>
          <p className="single-movie__overview">{movie.overview}</p>
          <p className="single-movie__genres">
            <label>Genres</label>
            {
              movieDetails.genres.map(genre => {
                console.log("genre: ",genre)
                return(
                  <div>{genre.name}</div>
                )
              })
            }
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (genre === "POPULAR") {
      dispatch(fetchMovies(request.fetchPopular(page)));
    } else if (genre === "NOW PLAYING") {
      dispatch(fetchMovies(request.fetchNowPlaying(page)));
    } else if (genre === "UP COMING") {
      dispatch(fetchMovies(request.fetchUpComing(page)));
    }
  }, [dispatch, genre, page]);

  return <div className="single-movie">{content}</div>;
};

export default SingleMoviePage;
```

I'm trying to make a movie website with **react-redux**. The issue is when I try to get movie details using `useEffect` and try to `map` that in:

```
<p className="single-movie__genres">
```

I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` error and I get empty object (`data: {}`) using `console.log("data: ", movieDetails)`.

But if I refresh the page everything works well and I get
data:

```
{
    adult: false, 
    backdrop_path: "/6MKr3KgOLmzOP6MSuZERO41Lpkt.jpg",
    ...
}
```

using `console.log("data: ", movieDetails)`. Why can't I get data when the page is first loaded?

Answer (score 1):

It is because your initial state does not contain "genres" array inside the object. And when react tries to handle

```
movieDetails.genres.map(...)
```

it fall down because movieDetails.genres is undefined (and undefined does not support map method of course). Either include empty array in you initial state like:

```
const [movieDetails, setMovieDetails] = useState({genres:[]})
```

or use "?" operator in your chain like:

```
movieDetails.genres?.map(...)
```

Comment: Thank u so much guys i understood.

Answer (score 1):

.map method is a prototype function for type array. you should declare `moviedetails` as an array like this when setting the default value using `useState` hook.

```
const [movieDetails, setMovieDetails] = useState([])
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a point that i dont understand.As far as i know when the component is first loaded first useEffect worked and filled my movieDetails with datas after that map func worked.I mean js works top to bottom and
shouldn't movieStatus be filled with data until it comes to the map function?

Comment: Yes, you are right, the very first time useEffect fires up when component is loaded. But with initial values you give. This is the first moment when state was born and changed its value. This is the moment the first useEffect starts working.